# Random seed for order of elements in Python's Set to List conversion

Tags: python, random, set

I was executing some code in a Jupyter notebook and noticed that each time I ran it, the output was different despite not explicitly putting randomness in my program.

I narrowed it down to a line that removes all repeated elements from a list.

```
l = list(set(l))
```

I noticed two things:

- If I re-run the same code in the same Jupyter kernel, I always get the same output for l, but
- If I open up another notebook, I get a different output.

Is there some kind of hidden random seed that is used for the set -> list conversion for a given kernel? How does it work under the hood, and what would I do if I wanted deterministic output from the above code?

Comment: Sets aren't ordered, why are you expecting consistent results?

Comment: If you want consistent results, sort the list

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that the line returns consistent results in a single kernel? Also, I can't use sort because the items in the list are of different types that are not sortable.

Comment: If they're not sortable, why does the order matter?

Comment: I guess it's not the most important thing, but just for reproducibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `set` functions almost the same as `dict`, with the `hash` of your object as the key. The default `__hash__` function of most objects (in CPython) relies on their `id`, which in turn relies on their address in the memory.

New kernel means objects have a different address, which means a different `id`, a different `hash`, and a different order of the iterator that the set gives.

This is implementation-dependent, so you cannot rely on it, all I can say is CPython, so far, works this way. The thing you can rely on is `set` not being (usefully) ordered.

If you need ordering, keep both the list and the set. If you want to remove repeats while preserving order, something like this will work:

```
def could_add(s, x):
    if x in s:
        return False
    else:
        s.add(x)
        return True

seen = set()
[x for x in l if could_add(seen, x)]
```

(Though I fully agree with Barmar's comment — if order matters, they should be sortable.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OrderedDict` instead of `set` to removes all repeated elements from a list and keep its order.
If you use python>=3.6, `dict` will also keep its order as the same as `OrderedDict`.

```
# python < 3.6
from collections import OrderedDict
res = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(yourlist))
```

```
# pyton >= 3.6
res = list(dict.fromkeys(yourlist))
```